# Setting global Luatex Umath primitives for an entire multi-page document

Tags: spacing, luatex, kerning

I would like to modify a \Umath* primitive for the entirety of the Lualatex document, containing multiple. It seems that using

```
\makeatletter 
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \Umathsubsupvgap\textstyle=0.5pt
}
```

in the preamble only works for the first page. After a `\clearpage`, the value is reset to its default again. How can I make it persistent?

Comment: The problem is that these values are reset whenever a math font is defined. You could try setting the value in \everymath and \everydisplay, that should.do the trick. Otherwise you can always set a mlist_to_hlist callback to set the value directly before it is used.

Comment: it may be reset but will not be reset by `\clearpage` as an alternative to resetting in everymath as @MarcelKrüger suggests you could also (possibly) modify the font table entries that are used to set the initial values, but as you haven't posted an example of the problem it is hard to say what is resetting the values.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. It's not the `clearpage` after all. I have tried to narrow it down but it seems there are multiple things in my document (there's a lot going on) that are resetting the values. I will see if I can narrow it down to a useful MWE, otherwise I'll probably go with `\everymath` for now.